# Ruby on Rails installing - Ubuntu 15

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu

I am trying to install RoR in Ubuntu 15(64 bit). I have done most of the installation process like installing rvm, ruby, mysql server, creating gemset.

```
rails new first_app
rvm gemset list
rvm gemset use rails3.2.13
rails new first_app
cd first_app/
bundle install
```

Above commads were executed successfully.

```
Ruby version 2.2.1
Rails version 3.2.13
```

When I am trying to start my server, I am getting error like below

```
rails s
/home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:270: warning: circular argument reference - now
/home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'coffee-rails'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
    from /home/ela/Documents/first_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

My Gem file ::

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Same error for 'uglifier' gem also so I removed those 2 gems. Then I am getting error in mysql adapter.

```
rails s
/home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:270: warning: circular argument reference - now
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:314:in `block in replace_gem': Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (can't activate mysql2 (~> 0.3.10), already activated mysql2-0.4.2. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.) (LoadError)
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:50:in `resolve_hash_connection'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:in `resolve_string_connection'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:25:in `spec'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:130:in `establish_connection'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/base.rb:720:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:88:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/ela/Documents/first_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ela/Documents/first_app/config.ru:3:in `require'
    from /home/ela/Documents/first_app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /home/ela/Documents/first_app/config.ru:in `new'
    from /home/ela/Documents/first_app/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

So I changed my gem mysql2 gem version to < 0.3

```
rake db:migrate --trace
/home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:270: warning: circular argument reference - now
============= WARNING FROM mysql2 =============
This version of mysql2 (0.2.24) isn't compatible with Rails 3.1 as the ActiveRecord adapter was pulled into Rails itself.
Please use the 0.3.x (or greater) releases if you plan on using it in Rails >= 3.1.x
============= END WARNING FROM mysql2 =============
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `accept' for nil:NilClass
/home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:7:in `to_sql'
/home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:38:in `select_values'
/home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:587:in `get_all_versions'
/home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:745:in `migrated'
/home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:668:in `current_version'
/home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:685:in `block in migrate'
/home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:685:in `each'
/home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:685:in `detect'
/home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:685:in `migrate'
/home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in `up'
/home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in `migrate'
/home/ela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@rails3.2.13/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:193:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/ela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/ela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/ela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/ela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/ela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/ela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/ela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/ela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/ela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/home/ela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/ela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/ela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/ela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/ela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/ela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/ela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/ela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/ela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Someone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**install nodejs**

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

then use

```
bundle install
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Its working now. I made a small change after installing nodejs , that is  gem "mysql2", "~> 0.3.20"